# Recognition of a sound (a word) with machine learning in python

Tags: python, audio, machine-learning

I'm preparing an experiment, and I want to write a program using python to recognize certain word spoken by the participants.

I searched a lot about speech recognition in python but the results are complicated.(e.g. CMUSphinx).

What I want to achieve is a program, that receive a sound file (contains only one word, not English), and I tell the program what the sound means and what output I want to see.

I have seen the sklearn [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html) about recognizing hand-written digits. I want to know if I can do something like the example:

1. training the program to return certain output (e.g. numbers) according to sound files from different people saying same word;
2. when take in new sound files from other person saying same word, return same values.

Can I do this with python and sklearn?
If so, where should I start?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written such program in text recognition. I can tell you if you chose to "teach" your program manually you will have a lot of work think about the variation in voice due to accents etc.

You could start [looking for a sound analyzer here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic) (Musical Analysis). try to identify the waves of a simple word like "yes" and write an alghorithm that percentages the variation of the soundfile. this way you can put a margin in to safe yourself from false-positives / vice-versa.

Also you might need to remove background noise from the soundfile first as they may interfer with your identification patterns.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Since I don't have much time to learn everything from zero, I decided to use online speech recognition apis like google speech api. I will try to dig further as soon as I got time.